# ASP.NET MVC Entity Framework 5 get true,false or both result

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have a table that I am filtering on. There is a four filters status, project, department, KPI

KPI is a boolean value. This filter has three value. True, False or both.

So, when the filter is true, it should return 'true' data, when the filter is 'false', return 'false' data; and when 'all' return both true and false data.

My code attached below, how can I enhance this code ? Can I write this with out if else conditions

```cs
var result = new List<TaskMaster>();
bool kpidata;
if (request.IsKPI == 1) { kpidata = true; } else { kpidata = false; }

//For KPI Tasks
if (request.IsKPI == 1 || request.IsKPI == 0)
{
    result = await _context.TaskMaster.Where(c => c.IsActive && (c.Status == request.Status || request.Status == "All") && (c.ProjectId == request.ProjectId || request.ProjectId == 0) && (c.IsKPI == kpidata) && (c.AssignedTo.DepartmentId == request.DepartmentId || request.DepartmentId == 0)).Include(y => y.TaskActionLogs)
        .Include(y => y.AssignedTo)
        .Include(y => y.AssignedBy)
        .Include(y => y.Project)
        .AsSplitQuery().ToListAsync();

//For Non-KPI Tasks
}
else {

    result = await _context.TaskMaster.Where(c => c.IsActive && (c.Status == request.Status || request.Status == "All") && (c.ProjectId == request.ProjectId || request.ProjectId == 0) && (c.AssignedTo.DepartmentId == request.DepartmentId || request.DepartmentId == 0)).Include(y => y.TaskActionLogs)
            .Include(y => y.AssignedTo)
            .Include(y => y.AssignedBy)
            .Include(y => y.Project)
            .AsSplitQuery().ToListAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Revise the code, both queries are almost identical except `c.IsKPI == kpidata` part.

Few ways to remove the redundant:

1. Write the `IQueryable` query and append the `.Where()` if the condition meets. You are fine to *append/extend* the query before the query is materialized (via `.ToList()`, `.First()` etc.).

```cs
var result = new List<TaskMaster>();
bool kpidata;
if (request.IsKPI == 1) { kpidata = true; } else { kpidata = false; }

IQueryable<TaskMaster> query = _context.TaskMaster
    .Where(c => c.IsActive 
        && (c.Status == request.Status || request.Status == "All") 
        && (c.ProjectId == request.ProjectId || request.ProjectId == 0) 
        && (c.AssignedTo.DepartmentId == request.DepartmentId || request.DepartmentId == 0));

//For KPI Tasks
if (request.IsKPI == 1 || request.IsKPI == 0)
{
    query = query.Where(c => c.IsKPI == kpidata);
}

result = await query.Include(y => y.TaskActionLogs)
    .Include(y => y.AssignedTo)
    .Include(y => y.AssignedBy)
    .Include(y => y.Project)
    .AsSplitQuery()
    .ToListAsync();
```

---

2. You can also migrate the `if` logic to the query too.

```
&& (!(request.IsKPI == 1 || request.IsKPI == 0) || c.IsKPI == kpidata)
```

If `!(request.IsKPI == 1 || request.IsKPI == 0)` returns `true`, the `c.IsKPI == kpidata` part will be omitted.

```cs
result = await _context.TaskMaster
    .Where(c => c.IsActive 
        && (c.Status == request.Status || request.Status == "All") 
        && (c.ProjectId == request.ProjectId || request.ProjectId == 0) 
        && (c.AssignedTo.DepartmentId == request.DepartmentId || request.DepartmentId == 0)
        && (!(request.IsKPI == 1 || request.IsKPI == 0) || c.IsKPI == kpidata))
    .Include(y => y.TaskActionLogs)
    .Include(y => y.AssignedTo)
    .Include(y => y.AssignedBy)
    .Include(y => y.Project)
    .AsSplitQuery()
    .ToListAsync();
```

This

```
(request.IsKPI == 1 || request.IsKPI == 0)
```

can also be revised to:

```cs
(new List<int> { 0, 1 }).Contains(request.IsKPI)
```